Unable to see UART output with Bare Metal Code with STM32F3DISCOVERY microcontroller
I was experimenting with UART on the STM32F3DISCOVERY microcontroller using bare metal code. I was unable to see an output on the terminal. I'm using the STM32CubeIDE. I am new to this so if there are any resources that could help me learn more, it would be very appreciated!
My code is below.
#include <stdint.h>

#define RCC_BASE 0x40021000 //memory address of rcc, add values to get other rcc registers
#define GPIOA_BASE 0x48000000
#define USART1_BASE 0x40013800
#define RCC_AHBENR_REGISTER (*(volatile uint32_t *) (RCC_BASE + 0x14)) //adress offset has value of 0x14
#define RCC_APB2ENR_REGISTER (*(volatile uint32_t *) (RCC_BASE + 0X18)) //address of apb2 which controsl usart1
#define USART1EN (1 << 14) //bit 14 enables uart
#define RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN (1 << 17) //bit 17 enables gpioa
#define     __IO    volatile
#define USART_ISR_TXE (1 << 7)
#define USART_ISR_TC (1 << 6)

typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;        /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;       /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;      /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;        /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;          /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;          /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;         /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,      Address offset: 0x1A */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;         /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];       /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
  __IO uint32_t BRR;          /*!< GPIO bit reset register,               Address offset: 0x28 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

typedef struct
{
      __IO uint32_t CR1;    /*!< USART Control register 1,                 Address offset: 0x00 */
      __IO uint32_t CR2;    /*!< USART Control register 2,                 Address offset: 0x04 */
      __IO uint32_t CR3;    /*!< USART Control register 3,                 Address offset: 0x08 */
      __IO uint32_t BRR;    /*!< USART Baud rate register,                 Address offset: 0x0C */
      __IO uint32_t GTPR;   /*!< USART Guard time and prescaler register,  Address offset: 0x10 */
      __IO uint32_t RTOR;   /*!< USART Receiver Time Out register,         Address offset: 0x14 */
      __IO uint32_t RQR;    /*!< USART Request register,                   Address offset: 0x18 */
      __IO uint32_t ISR;    /*!< USART Interrupt and status register,      Address offset: 0x1C */
      __IO uint32_t ICR;    /*!< USART Interrupt flag Clear register,      Address offset: 0x20 */
      __IO uint16_t RDR;    /*!< USART Receive Data register,              Address offset: 0x24 */
      uint16_t  RESERVED1;  /*!< Reserved, 0x26                                                 */
      __IO uint16_t TDR;    /*!< USART Transmit Data register,             Address offset: 0x28 */
      uint16_t  RESERVED2;  /*!< Reserved, 0x2A                                                 */
} USART_TypeDef;

#define GPIOA ((GPIO_TypeDef*) GPIOA_BASE)
#define USART1 ((USART_TypeDef*) USART1_BASE)
uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 8000000;
uint32_t BaudRate = 9600;

void uart_transmit(char c);

int main (void) {

        RCC_AHBENR_REGISTER |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN; //enable gpioa
        RCC_APB2ENR_REGISTER |= USART1EN; //enable usart
        //set pins pa9 and pa10 to alternate function
        GPIOA->MODER &= ~(00 << 18);
        GPIOA->MODER &= ~(00 << 20);

        GPIOA->MODER |= (0x2 << 18);
        //set pa10
        GPIOA->MODER |= (0x2 << 20);

        GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0x7 << 4); // enable alt function using afr7
        GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0X7 << 8);

        USART1->CR1 = 0X00;
        USART1->CR1 |= ((1 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 3)); //enable first bit, enabling usart

        USART1->BRR = 833; //set the baudrate

        //actually start writing data now; baudrate is 9600
        while (1) {
                uart_transmit('a');
                for (volatile int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i);
        }

}

void uart_transmit(char c) {
    while (!(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)); // Wait until transmit data register is empty
        USART1->TDR = c; //send the data
        while (!(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TC)); // check if it's complete
};

Although the code compiles properly, I still can't see the letter a outputted. I know that this is a problem with my code because it works just fine with the HAL. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit: This is the working HAL code, using the same peripheral USART1
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t str[] = "hello guys \r\n";

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
          HAL_Delay(10);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, str, sizeof(str), 100);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


What's wrong with the working HAL code? As a beginner, you should probably just use that. You can also use the low-level "LL" drivers instead of the HAL by opening the .ioc file and choosing that in the advanced settings of the project manager tab.

What stops you from using the sources of the HAL to look for differences?

Use the CMSIS-mandated device header. Read out and check/post content of UART and GPIO registers.
